# Sport accident occurrences vs practitioner's skill level

Tags: data-request, medical, sports

I remember having read a few years ago something along the lines of:

> injury risks among novice sports practitioners increase when they gain confidence -- due to a perceived skill level above their actual skill level.

To check that statement, I'm looking for some open data that associate accident events with the reported skill level of the practitioner. It doesn't matter if the skill level is assessed as some categorical (ex: "novice/advanced/expert/pro") or continuous data (ex: "years of practice").

Ideally, I would like data related to accidents in "action sports" like skateboard, roller, kitesurf, or alike where *" poor execution of the activity has to result in considerable risk of serious physical harm to the participant"* (to [quote wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_sport#Classification))

I will use the data to plot a graph for illustration purposes. I will not perform a deep or formal analysis of them. So, moderately reliable sources should be acceptable. I would prefer data from European countries or North America.

FWIW, Isearch through Google and https://catalog.data.gov but I didn't find any dataset recording the "skill level" of victims of sport accidents. But I'm outside of my field, so I may have lacked the proper keywords.

Comment: NEISS may have sports injuries (product based) but you’d have to use text mining to get the skill level.

Comment: Thanks @philshem. I checked that source since I initially posted the question, but I apparently have missed the relevant section/tool on the site :/

Comment: OK @philsem, To query the right DB, you have to scroll all the way down to find the relevant button. I missed that during my first visit. Anyway, I tried the query bellow. I don't think I could extract the practitioner skill level from the comment field. Or did I missed something else?

---

https://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/home.aspx 
`User Selected On: Most Recent 5 Years (2014 - 2018); Product Selection: SKATEBOARDS; Disposition Selection: 2=treated & Transferred, 4=treated & Admitted For Hospitalization, Hospitalized, 5=held For Observation`

Comment: from the bulk download, e.g. https://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/Data/Archived%20Data/2018/neiss2018.tsv , here's the records that mention "skateboard" https://pastebin.com/raw/6dLYkqGZ you'll see there is text descriptions. I've been working on a python parse, not done yet but perhaps useful for you https://github.com/philshem/play_neiss

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have the same data. Parsing shouldn't be an issue. But I can't see how to infer the skill level from the "narrative" fields. Eventually from the activity: "FELL OFF"-> Novice, "RIDING" -> regular, "TRICK" -> expert. 
But wouldn't that look too much like a wild guess?

Comment: How about skydiving? (Btw very likely true in skydiving that experts get hurt more often than novices) https://uspa.org/Safety-and-Training/Incident-Reports

Comment: Thanks, @philshem. No problem with skydiving. Anyway, the more I search for resources, the more it tends to prove the quote in the OP was wrong. I found a paper about ... Quidditch ... showing the novice practitioner have 0.5(sd 0.81) injuries per player, versus 0.93 (sd 1.16) for intermediate and 1.30(sd 1.22) for advanced practitioners. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321366163_INJURIES_IN_QUIDDITCH_A_DESCRIPTIVE_EPIDEMIOLOGICAL_STUDY